# Run a condition only if it is within specific date and time

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to get the code under the else to execute only if `now()` is more than the start date and start time.

For some reason, instead of returning the `strresponse` it executes the code after the else.

If I remove `starttime`, the code works fine but I also need it to run at that particular time of the day.

```
startdate= dateserial(2015, 08, 27 )
starttime =timevalue ("12:00:00 pm")
IF date() < startdate and time() < starttime then 

strResponse ="Auction begins at " & startdate & " " &starttime & " please wait untill auction has started"

else
```

Answer (score 0):

VBScript's date data type (technically a Variant) stores both the date and time so there's no need for two separate variables.

```
Dim dt
dt = DateSerial(2015, 8, 27) + TimeSerial(12, 0, 0)
```

Then you can just use the `Now()` function to get the current date and time for comparison:

```
If Now() < dt Then

    strResponse = "Auction begins at " & dt & "."

Else

    ' Time for auction

End If
```

To be honest, though, I don't see any reason why your original code shouldn't work. You did mean *noon* and not *midnight*, I assume.